# How to lock the layers into the same location reference

Tags: qgis, qgis-openlayers-plugin

I'm obviously very confused here. So I am using Google Maps as a base layer, as I want to get my new shapes in the right place for a map. Google Maps doesn't seem to allow me to zoom in particularly far, maybe I need to save it as an image rather than use a live map but that is a problem for another day. I select a CRS, enable on the fly, and ensure that the same CRS is used for a new shapeile layer. To my mind that should mean that when I use the Pan Map tool to move about a bit (and I mean only a bit) and my new shapes move position relative to the Google Map. My understanding was that the whoe point was to create maps that retained geographical integrity? Can someone please correct my assumption or my utilisation (preferably the latter)?

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. Are you saying your polygons are moving position but the Google Map base layer does not move at all?

Comment: Hi, no with both the layers (Google and Shapes) selected, if I use the Pan Map to drag the visual image in any direction, even by a very small margin, the Shapes are then in a different position on the Google map. They are not moving together in a uniform manner, meaning I can't make fine position adjustments to the shapes relative to the Map.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You run into a typical error with the Openlayers plugin. Switch to the QuickMapServices plugin instead. Make sure to visit `Web -> QuickMapServices -> Settings -> More services`, and click on `Get contributed pack`.

For best visual impact, use EPSG: 3857  as the **project** layer. The shapefile layer can have a different CRS.

Comment: And under those settings I should continue to use Google or would an alternative satellite resource be more effective, i.e. allow finer grained zoom?

Comment: On a global coverage, Google has a good resolution. But there may be services by local surveying authorities that provide better resolution. I don't konw them all ...